# How can I disable a specific lint error for Emacs Lisp using Flycheck?

Tags: flycheck

In Python with flake8 we can do that with #noqa in the end of line. How the same can be done with Emacs Lisp?

[image]

My ambition is to disable a particular lint error by just make a annotation with a comment like is provided in the above picture. This is possible in Emacs Lisp or there is a better way for it?

Comment: Please do not refer to `Python` and `flake8` here but describe what you want to know.

Comment: From a short analysis (maybe not right, maybe not comprehensive): `flycheck` uses `byte-compile` in a separate asynchronous Emacs process. So the list `byte-compile-warnings` is relevant for the issued warnings. Emacs is called with `-Q` and `--batch` so your initialization is ignored in the checker. But you can inject your code with options such as `flycheck-emacs-lisp-package-initialize-form`. See `flycheck-define-checker emacs-lisp` in `flycheck.el`.

Comment: I want ignore a lint error perline using Emacs Lisp as it's possible in other linters (like I said before).

Comment: My point is: Emacs experts like Drew, phils, Stefan, Dan, ... do not necessarily know Python well enough. It may be that you exclude them from giving you an expert advice with your reference to Python because they cannot be sure what exactly `flake8` does and what you expect. Better describe exactly what you expect. (E.g.: It could work like follows: If I add a comment `noqa` as in the following picture then the warning about the non-existing `prelude-packages` should be suppressed.)

Comment: By the way have you tried `(require 'prelude-packages nil t)` instead of `(require 'prelude-packages)`? You can even use something like `(unless (require 'prelude-packages nil t) (user-error "Library prelude-packages not found"))`.

Comment: The flycheck-emacs-lisp uses emacs lisp byte compiler but the byte compiler doesn't have such capability. So I think the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks for all the info guys! @Tobias I fixed using (require 'prelude-packages nil t). Can you answer the question providing this alternative? I'll accept as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoiding a specific flycheck decoration is not built-in but can easily be added.

The flycheck overlays are generated by `flycheck-add-overlay` which is luckily only called via the hook `flycheck-process-error-functions`.

Functions in that hook are run with a single arg -- the error -- until one of them succeeds.

The strategy is to add a function in `flycheck-process-error-functions` in front of `flycheck-add-overlay` that returns `t` when the error should be ignored.

That function can be added locally for buffers in `emacs-lisp-mode`.

In the following example flycheck errors are ignored in `emacs-lisp-mode` if the line with the error ends in `;noflycheck`. You can add the code to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

```el
(defcustom flycheck-elisp-noflycheck-marker ";noflycheck"
  "Flycheck line regions marked with this marker string are ignored."
  :type 'string
  :group 'flycheck)

(defun flycheck-elisp-noflycheck (err)
  "Ignore flycheck if line of ERR ends with `flycheck-elisp-noflycheck-marker'."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (cdr (flycheck-error-line-region err)))
    (looking-back flycheck-elisp-noflycheck-marker
          (max (- (point) (length flycheck-elisp-noflycheck-marker))
               (point-min)))))

(defun elisp-noflycheck-hook ()
  "Add the ;;;###noflycheck thing to elisp."
  (require 'flycheck)
  (add-hook 'flycheck-process-error-functions #'flycheck-elisp-noflycheck nil t))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'elisp-noflycheck-hook)
```

The application in your usage example would be like follows.

```el
(require 'prelude-packages) ;noflycheck
```

Answer (score 1):

In February 2020, the calculation method of the error region is refactored. The function `flycheck-error-line-region`is no longer available.

> (goto-char (cdr (flycheck-error-line-region err)))

Tobias's answer needs an update.

```
(goto-char (cdr (flycheck--exact-region err)))
```

Comment: `(goto-char (cdr (flycheck-error-region-for-mode err 'symbols)))`, actually.